# HashSet initialized using IEnumerable contains duplicate elements

Tags: c#, hashset

I want to be able to use `HashSet` constructed from `IEnumerable` collection of custom objects without duplicates. My custom object contains `id` and some other properties which aren't important for this question. I make a query to a database which returns an `IEnumerable` that I later use to construct a `HashSet` with the following code:

```
HashSet<Question> results = new HashSet<Question>(new QuestionComparer());
var result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Question>();
results.UnionWith(result);
```

The problem is there are duplicate records inside the `result` collection which I do not want.
The `QuestionComparer` class looks like this:

```
public class QuestionComparer : IEqualityComparer<Question>
{
    public bool Equals(Question x, Question y)
    {
        return x != null && y != null && x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Question obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I also tried overriding both `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods inside the `Question` class but no success. I considered looping through the collection and removing the duplicates, but it seems like it may become a performance problem...

EDIT: Azure DocumentDB that I am using apparently does not currently support a "distinct" type of query.

Comment: what type is `Id`?

Comment: It is a `string`

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Maybe you have `"HelloWorld" == "HeLlOwOrLd"` which will be false ?

Comment: So what's a problem? There are somehow multiple objects with same `id` in HashSet?

Comment: you shouldn't really use a hashset for this sort of thing - a dictioanry might be better.

Comment: I have nothing to do with the Ids. They are automatically generated by the database, so I don't think this is the source of problem. @RandRandom

Comment: Yes @Evk there are multiple objects with the same `Id`in my hashset

Comment: Why you use `results.UnionWith(result);` and not only the constructor: `new HashSet<Question>(result, new QuestionComparer())`. The result should be the same but i find your way confusing

Comment: @TimSchmelter my code used to look like that, but after all the unsuccessful attempts I guess I have tried a few "dumb"  things that I thought may work...

Comment: @Luki: Have you used the debugger to check what happens in `GetHashCode` and `Equals` with the duplicate `IDs`(you can make a conditonal breakpoint).

Comment: I don't see how it might happen with provided code. So indeed reproducable example is needed (examples of duplicate Ids also migth help).

Comment: pic of debugger insight window with duplicate ids in hashset or it did not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing a `public class QuestionComparer` you should override the methods of the existing  `Question` class

```
public class Question
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ID.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    {
        return (obj != null && obj is Question) ? (this.ID == ((Question)(obj)).ID) : false;
    }
}
```

So duplicates are not possible. Sample:

```
HashSet<Question> qh = new HashSet<Question>();
qh.Add(new Question() { ID = "1" });
qh.Add(new Question() { ID = "1" }); //will not be added
qh.Add(new Question() { ID = "2" });
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/wrFTaA

Comment: I have tried this again now and it seems I may have done some stupid mistake before since it works perfectly fine now... I am really not sure what went wrong before. Accepting this answer since you were the first.